# bat File won't Run in Windows 7

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a simple .bat file that references multiple .ps1 files on the server. The file is called RUNSHIP.bat and the only code is as follows:

```
& V:\SHIPPING\1001.ps1
& V:\SHIPPING\1002.ps1
& V:\SHIPPING\1003.ps1
```

The code is all correct, I can open the RUNSHIP.ps1 file in PowerShell and it runs it without any issues, however, when I create the .bat (or .cmd) file it doesn't even attempt to run any of the code. I have three other machines, all setup the same way, that run similar code with no issues (instead of RUNSHIP.bat it's RUNPACK.bat and etc) 

 I created a test .bat file and ran it fine on the computer. So the question is... Why won't the bat file run but the file runs fine when in Powershell? I am at my wits end with this.

Using Windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 0):

For reasons of safety, Microsoft set up PowerShell so that you can't run a PowerShell script by just typing its name at the command line. To run a PowerShell script from the command line, you need to explicitly include the PowerShell command:

```
 powershell -file filename.ps1
```

The `& filename` construct has no meaning in batch; it tells PowerShell to run a string as a command.

Batch is not PowerShell, and PowerShell is not batch; don't confuse the syntax of the two. There are good references for both [batch](https://ss64.com/nt/) and [PowerShell](https://ss64.com/ps/) at SS64.com

Comment: This didn't change anything, same issue is coming up. I have attempted that way before on my other computers but to no success. The $ filename construct has been great on my other machines, which is why this issue is so confusing to me. They were all built the same way...

Comment: If the code in your question is in the .bat file, it won't work; you'd need to replace the `&` with `powershell -file `. If not, then there's information missing or misrepresented, and you'll need to clarify.

Comment: The code above is all that is in my bat file. I replaced the & with powershell -file so the code now reads    " powershell -file V:\SHIPPING\1001.ps1      powershell -file V:\SHIPPING\1002.ps1 
    powershell -file V:\SHIPPING\1003.ps1 " ... This is now the only code in my bat file and it still will not run. If I move the bat file to one of my other computers it runs with no issues (using the & method) - what could possibly be different?

Comment: How are you running it? Double-clicking the .bat file? Try opening a command prompt and running the .bat file from there. Then you can see any messages that result.